# Duda procedimiento pop pilas c++

Tags: c++, lista, c++11, pilas

este código muestra en orden inverso el contenido de la lista enlazada a partir del nodo n con ayuda de una pila.  Una pregunta,si en vez de mostrar en orden inverso el contenido de la lista, lo quiero mostrar en orden normal, ¿cómo he de manejar la pila para que lo muestre así?

Este es el código que muestra los datos en orden inverso, yo quiero saber qué he de modificar para mostrar en orden normal, desde la primera posición hasta la última. Se agradece ayuda.

```
template <class T>
  ostream& dll_t<T>::write_reverse2(dll_node_t<T>* n, ostream& os) const {   



    stack_v_t<dll_node_t<T>*> stack;

    while (n != NULL) {
        stack.push_back(n);
        n = n->get_next();
    }

    while(!stack.empty()){

        stack.top()->write(os);
        stack.pop();
    }

    return os;
}

template <class T>
ostream& dll_t<T>::write_reverse2(ostream& os) const {

    reverse2(head_, os);

    return os;
}

template <class T>
class stack_v_t{
private:
vector_t<T> v_;
int top_;
public:
stack_v_t(int max_sz);
~stack_v_t(void);
bool empty(void);
T top(void);
void pop(void);
void push(T dato);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las pilas son o bien de tipo FIFO o bien de tipo LIFO. Es decir, el orden en el que se extraen los elementos viene fijado de antemano.

La que indicas tiene toda la pinta de ser de tipo LIFO y eso no vas a poder cambiarlo.

Aun así, para mostrar los datos en orden directo puedes optar por ignorar la pila:

```
template <class T>
ostream& dll_t<T>::write(dll_node_t<T>* n, ostream& os) const
{   
  while (n != NULL) {
    n->write(os);
    n = n->get_next();
  }

  return os;
}
```

Si quieres hacerlo con pilas las soluciones pasan a ser simplemente absurdas:

**Usar una pila FIFO**

No se si esta posibilidad está disponible. Sería absurdo porque en vez de mostrar los datos directamente (como te he propuesto al principio), almcenarías dichos resultados en una pila intermedia que no aportaría nada.

**Usar dos pilas LIFO**

En este caso lo absurdo es tener que recurrir a dos pilas para obtener el mismo resultado que obtienes con la primera respuesta:

```
template <class T>
ostream& dll_t<T>::write_reverse2(dll_node_t<T>* n, ostream& os) const
{   
    stack_v_t<dll_node_t<T>*> stack1, stack2;

    while (n != NULL) {
        stack1.push_back(n);
        n = n->get_next();
    }

    while(!stack1.empty()){
      stack2.push_back(stack1.top());
      stack1.pop();
    }

    while(!stack2.empty()){
      stack2.top()->write(os);
      stack2.pop();
    }

    return os;
}
```

Comment: Tal como me lo enseñaron a mí, todo son listas; si son FIFO entonces se les llama colas y si son LIFO se les llama pilas.

Comment: Yo intentaba tratarlo de forma más bien genérica pero tienes razón